# How to get label file from wav file with python?

Tags: python, wav

Hy, 
How to get .label file from .wav file with python? Could someone please share some link with example or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since `wav` files are a form of `riff` files, they can contain an *optional* `INFO` chunk. The information in that chunk is [tagged](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/RIFF.html#Info). However, there is no "label" tag. And since it is optional many `wav` files don't contain this chunk.

Note that the `wave` module from Python's standard library does *not* read or write the `INFO` chunk!